# How can I find out what files an .exe file called after I have run it to compile?

Tags: linux, command-line, dependencies, dynamic-library

I am running an .exe file in fortran but it doesn't seem to be finding one of the files which it should use to compile what it is compiling, so some of the settings are nul values. Is there a way I can find out what files it called when it ran, as that might help me track down the problem? I have tried echo and ls -l to see the links but they don't seem to show all the files the .exe called when it ran. I am relatively new to this, so if there is something that would show this can you be fairly explicit in your answer, e.g. 'compile the .exe then when in the same directory type xxx'. Thanks.

Comment: We really need more information. See [ask] and [mcve]. You did not even show us the error message. Which operating system do you use? There is dependency inspector in Windows.

Comment: This is a general question, i.e. If I run an .exe file, e.g. type in ' ./file.exe' in the linux command line to run a fortran file, is there a way to find out what files that .exe file called when it ran/compiled the resulting file. So there is no error message; I just would like to know how to find out what the .exe file called.

Comment: But you did not even tell us you were using Linux! Linux typically does not use .exe files, that is a MS Windows executable file suffix. Why do you even tag the question Fortran? You must use the relevant tags to get the right people for answering your question.

Comment: "so some of the settings are nul values" What does that mean? What kind of files do you mean? Libraries? Datafiles? What do you mean by "calling a file"? Is there a code in the file? Is it executable? What is it? Did you manage to compile your program at all or not?

Comment: @LAF it does sound like less of a programming question and more of a system admin style question. Try taking a venture over to Super User and asking how to find sub-processes in linux.